# how to trigger firebase realtime database using python 3.7

Tags: raspberry-pi3, python-3.7

## how to trigger firebase realtime database using python 3.7

actually i am refer https://pypi.org/project/FirebaseData/
but problem is that how to get my cridential for pass in `fire = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)`
if u have any other solution then tell me perfectly.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question. Are you asking what should be included in the `config` hash table/dictionary?

Comment: 'config = {
  "apiKey": "key",
  "authDomain": "project.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://project.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "project.appspot.com",
  "serviceAccount": "python.json"
}' how to get this cridential from firebase realtime database...or if u have any other solution for trigger using python then let me know that..